# how to bind the two values into text box for selection of dropdownlist item

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to do the invoice project and when I selected the dropdownlist item I should get the price and discount from database and display in the text boxes and iam getting the price value to text box but how can i get another value that is discount into text box how can i bind the second text box value...please some body help me out....thank u

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (! IsPostBack )
    {
        populatedropproduct();
    }
}

private void populatedropproduct()
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM invoice1", conn);
    com.Connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
    dropproduct.DataSource = null;
    dropproduct.DataTextField = "PRODUCT_NAME";
    dropproduct.DataValueField ="PRICE";
   dropproduct.DataBind();
    dropproduct.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Item--", "0"));
    com.Connection.Close();
}
protected void txtinvoice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void txtcustomer_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void dropproduct_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String title = dropproduct.SelectedItem.Value;
    title = dropproduct.SelectedItem.Value;
    try
    {
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT PRICE,[DISCOUNT%]  FROM                  invoice1 WHERE [PRODUCT NAME]=@title", conn);
        SqlParameter param0 = new SqlParameter();
        param0.ParameterName = "@title";
        param0.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        param0.Value = title;
        com.Parameters.Add(param0);
        com.Connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
       txtprice.Text = title.ToString();
        com.Connection.Close();
        com.Connection.Dispose();
    }
    catch(Exception s)
    {
       HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Error Occured " + s.Message);
    }            
}
```

Comment: this `System.Data.SqlDbType.Int` should be `System.Data.SqlDbType.Varchar`

Comment: thank u.....its worked and how can i bind another text value that is discount value into text box from data base like price in the above code plz help me

Answer (score 0):

```
param0.ParameterName = "@title";
param0.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
param0.Value = title;
```

Your code says param `@title` is integer but you try put into it string.

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
param0.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
```

you set the type or your parameter to `Int`. But your `PRODUCT NAME` surely is a string. So change that line to

```
param0.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
```

or

```
param0.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar;
```

according to the type of the `PRODUCT NAME` column type.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
param0.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
```

With

```
param0.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Varchar;
```